# Automate Enterprise Architect Configuration

Tags: c#, svn, configuration, add-in, enterprise-architect

We are using `Enterprise Architect` for our models.

EA can be integrated with version control system, for that, it is required to set configuration from `EA` to the directory in `SVN` folder- in which the XMI files of packages will be stored.

The configuration settings process is a long and annoying process which we would like to be done automatically.

Is there a way to do this programmatically?

UPDATE: This is the window which requires the manual configuration for each machine.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you referred to the best practices prescribed by Sparx? http://www.sparxsystems.com/WhitePapers/Version_Control.pdf

Whilst I agree it could be a time-consuming process to setup version control for the first time, there are several tricks which could make it less cumbersome.
E.g. COnfiguring the packages (or branches) in one model and then sharing the same to the rest of the team, and just letting them specify the Working Copy of the rewpository.

PS - It is also best not to interfere with the package structure in your SVN folder, and let EA take care of the same

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have read the "Best Practices" and would like to get more information about the "tricks" you have mentioned. The model is shared already, the configurations names were defined once for everyone, but each user has to set the paths for each configuration manually. This is the action I would like to automate. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The following was from Sparx Systems Forum (From Helmut), You have to do four things to put a package under version control.

1. Set the unique ID in %APPDATA%\SPARX_Systems\EA\paths.txt
2. Use API VersionControlAdd(..)
3. Set the svn path in registry
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SPARX Systems\EA400\EA\Options\VC_SVNExePath
4. svn Timeout in registry (VC_TIMEOUT)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would follow it there. Thanks for the notification about the similar post.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. The API does not support selecting version control provider etc, but it does support adding/removing packages to/from version control and checking them in and out once the provider is set.

The methods are in the `Package` class (in the help file under Automation and Scripting -- Enterprise Architect Object Model -- Reference -- Repository Package -- Package Class):

```
VersionControlAdd()
VersionControlCheckin()
VersionControlCheckinEx()
VersionControlCheckout()
VersionControlGetLatest()
VersionControlGetStatus()
VersionControlPutLatest()
VersionControlRemove()
VersionControlResynchPkgStatus()
```

`Repository.VersionControlResynchPkgStatuses()` resynchronizes all version-controlled packages, but that's the only project-level version control method in the API.

You don't have to write an Add-In if it's a one-off thing. A stand-alone application has access to the Object Model API, whereas an Add-In (which is integrated into EA) also has access to the Add-In Model API (see Automation and Scripting -- Enterprise Architect Add-In Model).

The Add-In Model API fires a number of events when model elements are created, updated, etc, but no events are triggered by version control changes. So if you only need to add a number of packages to the version control repository, a stand-alone application can do that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. From your detailed answer I understand I can automate the version control actions which are enabled for controlled packaged. I'm sure it would be useful for the close future, but first I would like to automate the configuration definition. Please take a look on my updated post. Thanks in advance!